# copy last value from another file have the same word(selected country) excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code the allow for the user entered the name of country and the VBA search from another file the same country from column (1)and then copy only the last cumulative value related to this country in column (4) but still gave me an errors.

The image from this file attached
[image]

As you see from figure, i want only to copy last value for Nepal which is 1600000.

And the code attached:

```vb
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim countryName As Variant
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim mainFile As Workbook
    Dim mainsheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim selectedRow As Long
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set mainFile = ThisWorkbook
    
    Sheets("SelectFile").Activate
    Set mainsheet = ActiveSheet
    countryName = Range("B2").Value
    
    Sheets("Data").Activate
    Set dataSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls,(*.csv*),*csv*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Set sht = ActiveSheet
        
        Lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
       
        For i = 1 To Lastrow
        
            If Cells(i, 1) = countryName Then
            
                selectedRow = i
                Exit For
            End If
            Next i
       OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(selectedRow, 4), Cells(selectedRow, 4)).Copy
        mainFile.Activate
        dataSheet.Activate
        
        Range("I15").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        OpenBook.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error and what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop - you can use Find() to locate the last instance.

Untested:

```vb
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim countryName As Variant
    Dim mainFile As Workbook
    Dim mainsheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim f As Range, rngFind As Range
    
    Set mainFile = ThisWorkbook
    Set mainsheet = mainFile.Sheets("SelectFile")
    Set dataSheet = mainFile.Sheets("Data")
    
    countryName = mainsheet.Range("B2").Value
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                   Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", _
                   FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls,(*.csv*),*csv*")
                   
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen, ReadOnly:=True)
        Set sht = OpenBook.Worksheets(1)
        
        Set rngFind = sht.Columns("B")
        'find the last value...
        Set f = rngFind.Find(what:=countryName, lookat:=xlWhole, after:=rngFind.Cells(1), _
                             searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.Offset(0, 2).Copy dataSheet.Range("I15")
        End If
        
        OpenBook.Close False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```